# GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.update failed with error: The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Cannot get any answer about this error

> "GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.update failed
>   with error: The user does not have sufficient permissions for this
>   file"

.

```
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  // Log the name of every file in the user's Drive.
  var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileID = file.getId();
    if(file.getOwner()){
      if(email == file.getOwner().getEmail()){
        Drive.Files.update({copyRequiresWriterPermission:true}, fileID);
        Logger.log(file.getOwner().getEmail());
      }
    }
  }
```

I am trying to update the sharing access of my file from my google drive. But this error always shows. No idea about this one.

Comment: Show execution transcript

Comment: Log the filedId before `Drive.Files.update({copyRequiresWriterPermission:true}, fileID);` to see which file gives you the error and check the permissions for this file.

Comment: The file before the error was a google site which doesn't have "Disable option to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers" maybe this is the reason why i am getting an error?

Comment: @Newbie So, check the mimetype before `.update`